# UIAutomation not enabled in Settings error message

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation, tweak

When I am writing a tweak application with 
`[[UIATarget localTarget].frontMostApp isVisible]` in main.mm main function, I get the exception saying

> *** exception UIAutomation is not enabled on this device. UIAutomation must be enabled in Settings. ***

But I have Enabled Settings->Developer->Enable Automation UI in device. iOS version:8.1.2 and 8.0.1 jail broken.

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        @try
        {

            [[UIATarget localTarget].frontMostApp isVisible];

            if ([UIATarget localTarget].springboard.pid == nil)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception)
        {
            NSLog(@"*** exception %@ ***",exception);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I have seen this link https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/issues/707 and some Apple reference documents for UIATarget frontMostApp but I found no solution so far.

Is this problem with the iOS version ? How can I solve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is a tweak application?? pl provide some more details.

Comment: @satheeshwaran  Basically,this tweak application objective is to launch the app and repeat the actions performed on the same app reading a file from particular directory which contains the details of earlier performed actions.

Comment: please provide links for detailing what a tweak application is.

Comment: Do you mean what is tweak?I guess its to deal with UIAutomation.framework

Comment: Hey bascially the question is simple,irrespective of enabling in settings,i get the error "UIAutomation not enabled in device" when i call target.frontMostApp.

Answer (score 1):

Your UIAuomation settings plist will be separately created for each application in case of tweaks.

Enable it in `/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/XXXXXXXX-ACAB-4FC9-AE3E-XXXXXX/Library/Preferences/com.apple.UIAutomation.plist` and `Reboot` your device to get rid of this error.